# How do I find the distribution for X + Z?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to calculate the distribution for X + Z which normally means I have to find the CDF. Is that correct? But I am not sure how.

I know that

$X \sim Exp(2)$ and $Z \sim Exp(2)$ and that X and Z is independent.

How do I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that (good) answers can be accepted $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$?

Comment: You can mark good answers as accepted by clicking on the check mark of the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be the laws of $X$ and $Z$ respectively. Since $X$ and $Z$ are independent, the law of $X+Z$ is given by the **convolution** $\mu \star \nu$, where for every measurable set $A$, one has
$$\mu \star \nu\big(A\big) := \int_X \mu(A-x) \operatorname{d}\nu(x) $$

Comment: You mean independ**e**nt?

Comment: @callculus Yes indeed, pardon my French ;)

Comment: No problem - I´m German ;)

Comment: Unhabhängigkeit ist mein lieblings Wort :)

Comment: My three favorite words in french are liberté, égalité and fraternité

Comment: Are you able to elaborate? I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. Does law mean distribution or? What would the integral look like? I am not quiet sure whether or not these type of questions would be a part of our exams as these type of questions are from previous exams which now has been changed as the course has changed.

Comment: @MathiasNissen The law of $X$ is the measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(A) = p(X \in A)$. The repartition function is then given by $x \mapsto \mu(]-\infty;x[)$.